# How can I easily repeat emacs find-grep

Tags: emacs

I would like to be able to easily repeat a find-grep.  Ideally, it would work on recompile, which is what the g char runs.  But at least when I run find-grep, it should start with the string that I last used in the same session, as a default.  I have searched, but not found...  Kind of ironic to be searching for an answer about searching...

Comment: It seems to me that this is a **bug** in `rgrep` and `find-grep` (aka `grep-find`). They should define a better value for `revert-buffer-function`. Please consider filing a bug report (enhancement request): `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Filed a report. Got a response that it does work. Tested some myself. It seems to work unless I am in a directory with a rails project under rvm. Not sure but it seems like there is some ruby/rails/rvm emacs package I am using that is breaking it. Not sure how to look for that. Not a huge deal.

Comment: Bisect your init file to find out which (e.g. ruby, rails, rvm) library is causing the problem. If nothing you are doing yourself is responsible for the problem, consider reporting it to the maintainer of the culprit library.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't `g` do what you request already? For me it does.

But I'm talking about `find-grep-dired`, which might be useful for what you want to do.

I use [`find-dired+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el), in addition to vanilla `find-dired.el`.  But I think that the latter probably does the right thing too.

Here's the doc string of `find-grep-dired` from `find-dired+.el`:

```
find-grep-dired is an interactive Lisp function in `find-dired+.el'.

(find-grep-dired DIR REGEXP &optional DEPTH-LIMITS EXCLUDED-PATHS)

Find files in DIR containing a regexp REGEXP.
The output is in a Dired buffer.
The `find' command run (after changing into DIR) is essentially this,
where LS-SWITCHES is `(car find-ls-option)':

  find . -exec grep find-grep-options REGEXP {} \; LS-SWITCHES

Thus REGEXP can also contain additional grep options.

Optional arg DEPTH-LIMITS is a list (MIN-DEPTH MAX-DEPTH) of the
 minimum and maximum depths.  If nil, search directory tree under DIR.

Optional arg EXCLUDED-PATHS is a list of strings that match paths to
 exclude from the search.  If nil, search all directories.

When both optional args are non-nil, the `find' command run is this:

  find . -mindepth MIN-DEPTH -maxdepth MAX-DEPTH
         \( -path *edir1* -o -path *edir2* ... \)
         -prune -o -exec grep find-grep-options REGEXP {} \;
         LS-SWITCHES
```

Comment: I value seeing the line in the output...  I know about find-grep-dired.  I have considered it.  I understand that it supports the g...

Comment: OK. Wrt repeating a command (any command) with the same arguments, you do know about `C-x  ESC ESC`, I assume (?).

Comment: Or `C-x M-C-[` (which I find easier to type).

Comment: @phils: You really find that easier to type? We must have different keyboards or different fingers. ;-)

Comment: I found myself getting a bit confused while I was making that comment (I tried to type `C-x M-{` instead), and I've realised why -- `C-x M-C-[` isn't actually what I use :) I use `C-x M-:` (which I originally found mnemonically similar to the `M-:` binding, but it's all muscle memory these days, and I got mixed up when I saw the `C-x ESC ESC` version :) That said, both alternatives I've mentioned are pretty similar for typing. Not having to reach for the `ESC` key is the main reason I say I find it easier, but different keyboards or fingers are certainly another possibility :)

Comment: About repeat command...  I often go on to other things while compile or find is running.  I want something in that buffer so it knows how to repeat the compile command that was used in that compile buffer.  For both find-grep and for the compile command that I use to run cucumber and rspec tests for those types of files, if I do a "g" in that buffer, which is supposed to rerun it, it runs it with "make -k" instead of the command that I used.  Can anyone point me to where I would automatically set the command to run when typing g in a compile buffer to the command that created it? Thanks!

Comment: To set the command to run: Try setting (the buffer-local value of) `compile-command` to the command you want. You can likely do that programmatically, as part of whatever command you use to launch the OS command.

Comment: Wrt repeating, just to make sure you're aware of it: You have available the entire history of previously used complex commands, when you do `C-x ESC ESC`. Just use `M-p` or `M-r`, as usual when something is read from the minibuffer.